# How to put RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter in monitor mode using iwconfig?

Tags: wireless-networking, debian-wheezy

I w as testing the security of my wifi network following [this](http://lifehacker.com/5873407/how-to-crack-a-wi-fi-networks-wpa-password-with-reaver) guide 
and I am using "RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter" in my debian pc for this purpose.

`iwconfig` lists :

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

when I try to put it into monitor mode by issuing , `sudo iwconfig wlan mode monitor` , i get :

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan ; Operation not permitted.
```

and when I issue , `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`:

```
Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
1794    avahi-daemon
1795    avahi-daemon
2174    NetworkManager
2858    wpa_supplicant


Interface   Chipset     Driver
```

I have'nt installed any drivers for the same and yet I can connect to my wifi access point and surf Internet without any trouble using this device but couldn't complete the above procedure.

What may be the reason for the same ? And How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Monitor mode is not hugely common. You need driver *and* hardware support, and there's very few use cases for them, Wikidevi seems to suggest that [monitor mode is unsupported for your specific adaptor](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/R8712u), and if so, you can't switch to monitor mode

In theory if it *did* support it `iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor` SHOULD work, so its not your command, its probably the hardware